# Multiple webserver docker containers listening on different host IPs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a server with multiple IP addresses.  I want different nginx containers to listen on `:80` and `:443` on two IPs on this host.

`/srv/www1/docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:mainline-alpine
  container_name: www1
  ports:
    - "69.69.69.1:80:80/tcp"
    - "69.69.69.1:443:443/tcp"
```

`/srv/www2/docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:mainline-alpine
  container_name: www2
  ports:
    - "69.69.69.2:80:80/tcp"
    - "69.69.69.2:443:443/tcp"
```

*Either* container can start first without problems, but if I try to start the second container (`www2` for example), while the first is already running, the first container is stopped and this error is thrown:

```
WARNING: Found orphan containers (www1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
```

No, they are not the same container- the `docker-compose.yml` files are not even in the same directory.  It seems like docker uses the `image:` and `ports:` fields to *identify* containers, but ignores the IP addresses.

Is this a bug?  How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Running the containers from a single docker-compose file is working.

`/srv/www/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:

    nginx1:
      image: nginx:mainline-alpine
      container_name: www1
      ports:
        - "69.69.69.1:80:80/tcp"
        - "69.69.69.1:443:443/tcp"
    
    nginx2:
      image: nginx:mainline-alpine
      container_name: www2
      ports:
        - "69.69.69.2:80:80/tcp"
        - "69.69.69.2:443:443/tcp"
```

Check it with `ss`:

```
# ss -tln | grep ':80 \|:443 '
LISTEN 0      4096           69.69.69.1:443        0.0.0.0:*          
LISTEN 0      4096           69.69.69.2:443        0.0.0.0:*          
LISTEN 0      4096           69.69.69.1:80         0.0.0.0:*          
LISTEN 0      4096           69.69.69.2:80         0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be the solution? It sounds like more information that should be edited into the question instead.